# Covering the branch code : Karma & Angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing, automated-tests, karma-jasmine, karma-coverage

I am trying my hands at testing with karma-jasmine. I am getting a yellow indication showing Branch is not covered for the following code.

I have posted the test case for the same as well.

Can anyone help me cover the test case for the branch?

[image]

```
const mockResponseRecommendation = { 
    status: 'success', 
    data: [ 
      { 
        resourceId: 10, 
        notes: null, 
        typeOfDelay: 'Time', 
        recommendationDate: '11/28/2021', 
        minValue: 5, 
      }, 
    ], 
  };
```

Comment: can you share the value of mockResponseRecommendation please?

Comment: Edited the data in question

Comment: The yellow indicators tell you that your tests don't cover the cases when `response.data` is null / undefined and when `this.highAlertInfo` is null / undefined. I don't really understand what you are struggling with.

Comment: I am not sure how to make the response set to null and test the case. Can you help me with it. 
i have tried setting the req.flush to null still no luck

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems as you. Whenever I encounter this situation I usually dont try to test this branch but instead mofifying my code to remove this branch. Because you dont have a code to run if this response.data and this.highAlertinfo doesnt exist, you can just put those in a variable and use the as keyword. For example, if response.data is a number you can add before the first if: const dataResponse = response.data as number and the use the newly created variable instead same thing for the other uncovered branch.